# Keycloak with 10 million realms

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

We are on latest keycloak version with Quarkus distribution. We have a usecase where we will need to create about 10 million realms. Each realm would have limited set of client/groups/users/roles/idps. Most of the realms would have mostly 10/12 users, 3/5 groups and roles, 20/25 clients.

I am aware that keycloak performance starts degrading when we hit 500 realms mark. But what I understood is that happens only with the admin UI and login flows would still be fine.

I wanted to check if this is the right approach or is there any other way we could achieve this? I don't want to create single realm and add 10 million groups where each group would act as a realm. This approach has security/maintenance issues.

Did anyone setup keycloak for this kind of dataset? I would really appreciate if you could share your findings with the performance and any suggestion on how to do it in better way.

Thanks,
Sagun

Comment: I can't imagine a use case with millions of realms - unless it's a realm per user / per device. Either way I don't think that's a reasonable design choice and I would expect serious performance / scalability and maintenance challenges if you proceed that way.

Comment: @kellyfj we have small customers (mom/pop shops). Adding them as separate realms would make more sense for us instead of creating separate groups which would add more security overhead.

Comment: What about having a dedicated Keycloak cluster for each customer (or for each batch of 500 customer) if you could? That way you should not be worry about high number of realms.